# How to access mapped network drive from java application?

Tags: java, mapped-drive

I have a network drive mapped as:

net use h: \ip\servername

I have a normal java application that is going to read a txt file from that drive.

Code:

```
File file = new File("H:\\MyFile.txt");

try {
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication25.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

When i run this program from my computer (windows 7 or from another computer with windows vista), the program runs without any problem.

However, when i run this program from a computer with Windows 10, i get the following error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: H:\MyFile.txt
```

But if i run the application using the following code it works:

```
File file = new File("\\ip\servername\MyFile.txt");

try {
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication25.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

How can i use the mapped drive letter instead of using the full address?

Comment: the address is \\ip\sername, i forgot a \

Comment: When I try your code with a mapped network drive it works fine. Are you sure the drive is mapped when you try to access it?

Comment: yes, it is mapped in all computers with the exact same letter before the execution

Comment: Which JRE/JDK are you using? Have you tried different ones?

Comment: in my pc : JRE: 1.8.0_161; JDK: jdk1.8.0_65; in the other computer: jre:1.8.0.201; JDK 1.8.0.201.

Comment: in problem computer: jre:1.8.0.201; JDK 1.8.0.201. in another user's pc(ok): jre: 1.8.0_60

Comment: 181 and 201 are working for me. Are you sure you added the the drive as persistent? you said `net use h: \ip\servername` but you need to have it added with `/persistent:yes`. Other than that, "have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: yes, the drive is added as persistent and i have tried turning it off and on.

Comment: Well, then there is really nothing I can Do I suppose, sorry. I am not able to reproduce the problem at all. Hopefully you will find a solution to your problem.

Comment: It works using this file? `File file = new File("\\ip\servername\MyFile.txt");` This does not even compile.

Comment: Thanks jalako, i will use the solution using the ip address. dpr: yes, i copied it wrong, it should be "\\\\ip\\servername\\Myfile.txt".

Answer (score 3):

Got same issue. Resolved by editing windows registry

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
```

If it works, it means your IT dept. should manage better network policies.

Answer (score 1):

using \\ip\servername\file.txt worked

Comment: This is not an answer to the question the link you provide is not a mapped drive but a UNC address to a network drive. While they may seem to be the same - they are not. A mapped drive is a link to the physical connection.